# RoR: tests pass locally but fail with Travis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, travis-ci

I am building a Ruby on Rails application and I’m in front of an issue with my tests. I try to assert that an article has a picture linked to it (using paperclip gem).
It’s works properly in local but failed when travis run tests units.

Do someone has an idea about what’s wrong with my test ?

**Here is my test**:

```
  test 'should have picture linked' do
    @home_post = posts(:home)
    attachment = fixture_file_upload 'images/bart.png', 'image/png'
    Picture.create(image: attachment, attachable_type: 'Post', attachable_id: @home_post.id)
    assert @home_post.pictures?, 'should have picture linked to home article'
  end
```

**Here is the methods pictures?**:

```
  def pictures?
    pictures.online.first.present? && pictures.online.first.image.exists?
  end
```

My guess is that fixtures are not uploaded with travis and the « exists?" method always return false.
Is there a way to make travis to pass this test ?

Thanks for your help

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2.4
- Ruby 2.2.2
- Rails Minitest (not rspec)

Comment: We could use an error message you're getting in this test.

Comment: There is no error message except the one I added myself: 'should have picture linked to home article'

Comment: Which storage adapter are you using? You'll likely need to switch to `Storage::FileSystem` when running in test environment. There are several reasons it's undesirable for your CI server to pummel S3.

Comment: I am storing paperclip assets locally without S3 or dropbox cloud storage. How can I switch of adapter for Travis ?